# Immanuel Kant and his views on a profession

Tags: ethics

How would Kant value a profession? Do you think disrespecting a profession will fall in the violation of imperfect duty? Explain.

Comment: This question is rather vague. What do you mean by "disrespecting a profession"? What do you mean by "value" professions? Are you talking about work in general or specific types of work that Kant might have mentioned in his work?

Comment: work in general. Disrespecting as in not giving a profession enough importance or trying to demean it

Comment: Sounds a bit like an assignment task. What are your own thoughts and research outcomes so far?

Comment: It must be the time of year for take-home exams. We're getting a rash of homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading

> Answering the Question: What Is Enlightenment?

I found a translated version [Here](https://www.northampton.edu/Documents/Subsites/HaroldWeiss/Modern%20Philosophy/Kant_What_is_Enlightenment.pdf)

So, an imperfect duty is both the duty of self-improvement and the duty to aid others.

If it were possible that by disrespecting a profession he was aiding others in any sense, it would be justifiable. However, seeing as we aren't talking about criticizing particular practices within a profession, or particular practitioners, it is highly unlikely that such a useful assault could occur. If you can think of one, please do bring it forward.

As far as I can see, this goes against imperfect duty.